# How is it possible for some code to take more time to run given the same inputs seemingly just because it's in a loop?

Tags: c++, loops, benchmarking

Prelude/Context: I've just started learning c++ and decided to write up some code that would apply a single qubit gate to a quantum register where the register is held in an array called amplitudes and the four elements of the single qubit gate are a,b,c,d. I've tried to write a version that avoids an if statement that appeared in my first pass and to my initial delight, it seemed to have a slight performance enhancement (~10%). If I change the number of qubits in the register or which qubit I target with the gate, I get a similar result. I then tried to make a loop that would perform timing comparisons for a various target qubits and something very strange (to me at least) happened. The alternative function I wrote that avoids the if statement doubled its execution time (from ~0.23 to 0.46 seconds) whereas the function with the if statement had its execution time unaffected (~0.25 seconds). This leads me to my question:

**How can code that, when given the same inputs in either case, take longer to execute inside of a loop that iterates those inputs?**

For example, if I run a test giving 25 qubits and target qubit 1, the "no if" function wins. Then, if I write a while loop to do a comparison at 25 qubits for each value of target starting at 1, the "no if" function takes double the time to execute even on the first iteration when it receives identical input to the prior case. Interestingly, if I just include the while loop and make it an infinite while loop by putting "True" in the while statement or by commenting out the increment statement target+=1, the function no longer takes double time. This phenomenon requires the loop and the increment from what I can tell.

Code below in case this is a simple coding error in a new language I'm less familiar about. I'm using Visual Studio 2017 community edition with all default settings except that I'm using the "release" build for faster code execution. Commenting out the while statement and the corresponding closing curly brace makes the "no if" timing double.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <complex>

void matmulpnoif(std::complex<float> arr[], std::complex<float> out[], int numqbits, std::complex<float> a,
std::complex<float> b, std::complex<float> c, std::complex<float> d, int target)
{
    long length = 1 << (numqbits);
    long offset = 1 << (target - 1);
    long state = 0;
    while (state < length)
    {
        out[state] = arr[state] * a + arr[state + offset] * b;
        out[state + offset] = arr[state] * c + arr[state + offset] * d;
        state += 1 + offset * (((state%offset) + 1) / offset);
    }
}

void matmulpsingle(std::complex<float> arr[], std::complex<float> out[], int numqbits, std::complex<float> a,
std::complex<float> b, std::complex<float> c, std::complex<float> d, int target)
{
    long length = 1 << (numqbits);
    int shift = target - 1;
    long offset = 1 << shift;
    for (long state = 0; state < length; ++state)
    {
        if ((state >> shift) & 1)
        {
            out[state] = arr[state - offset] * c + arr[state] * d;
        }
        else
        {
            out[state] = arr[state] * a + arr[state + offset] * b;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    int numqbits = 25;
    long arraylength = 1 << numqbits;
    complex<float>* amplitudes = new complex<float>[arraylength];
    for (long i = 0; i < arraylength; ++i)
    {
        amplitudes[i] = complex<float>(0., 0.);
    }
    amplitudes[0] = complex<float>(1., 0.);
    complex<float> a(0., 0.);
    complex<float> b(1., 0.);
    complex<float> c(0., 0.);
    complex<float> d(1., 0.);
    int target = 1;
    int repititions = 10;
    clock_t startTime;
    //while (target <= numqbits) {
        startTime = clock();
        for (int j = 0; j < repititions; ++j) {
            complex<float>* outputs = new complex<float>[arraylength];
            matmulpsingle(amplitudes, outputs, numqbits, a, b, c, d, target);
            delete[] outputs;
        }
        cout << float(clock() - startTime) / (float)(CLOCKS_PER_SEC*repititions) << " seconds." << endl;
        startTime = clock();
        for (int k = 0; k < repititions; ++k) {
            complex<float>* outputs = new complex<float>[arraylength];
            matmulpnoif(amplitudes, outputs, numqbits, a, b, c, d, target);
            delete[] outputs;
        }
        cout << float(clock() - startTime) / (float)(CLOCKS_PER_SEC*repititions) << " seconds." << endl;
        target+=1;
    //}
    delete[] amplitudes;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should measure the mean execution time of multiple runs for each function, probably discarding the first few runs. Also, only measure what you want to measure: don't allocate/deallocate inside you loop (as Qubit suggested), and consider passing parameters by reference instead of by value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, I can not yet post comments, so I'll post this here even though it may not be a complete answer.

In general, the question you pose is difficult. The compiler performs optimisations, and the two cases are different code so they get optimised differently.

On my machine, for instance (Linux, GCC 7.3.1), with only -O3 enabled, the `matmulpnoif` is always faster (4.8s vs 2.4s or 4.8s vs 4.2s - these times are not measured with `clock()`, depending on whether the loop is there or not). If I had to guess what happens in this case, the compiler might realise that `offset` is always one, and optimise the remainder operation away (division is by far the most expensive operation you have in there). However, it could be a combination of other things as well.

Another thing to note, `clock()` should NOT be used to measure time. It counts the number of clock ticks, for instance, if you parallelise the code across 2 threads the number will be twice the time (assuming your code doesn't wait anywhere - which does not appear to be the case on my machine). If you wish to measure time, I suggest you look at `<chrono>`, the `high_resolution_clock` should do the trick.

Another side note, there is no need to keep allocating and deallocating the output array, you can simply use the one, that way you will waste less time. But above all, if you're using C++ I suggest you put all of this in a class, as it is you are passing many parameters to each function, it can make things both difficult to read and slower, if you pass a lot of data (as it gets copied).

And a second note, since you are using bit shifts, it might be safer to use unsigned variables as the right shift `>>` does not have a strict definition of what it pads with with signed variables. At the very least it's something to keep in mind, it might be padding 1s on that side.

Comment: Based on my fiddling with this the compiler optimizing the expensive operations based on the ability to "know" what target would be is the culprit. I wonder what's different about the compiling on my machine compared to yours that makes the "single" function expensive in either case, but that's another question in and of itself. Thanks for the suggestions for improvements.

Comment: Well, if I understood your post correctly, you're on Windows using MSVC, so the compilers are different. As a result they optimise differently. You can try gcc, Intel C++ etc and see what which works best (in this case).